# C++ : compile time assert the value of a floating point number

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I am using C++ 11.
I have a floating point number.

```
float some_float = 3.0;
```

Now I want to compile time check that this number is greater than some value. Say that I want to compile time assert that `some_float` is greater than `1.0`. i am trying this:

```
static_assert(some_float > 1.0);
```

But, it errors out complaining,

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert(some_float > 1.0);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Question:**
what is wrong that I am doing?
How can I assert at compile time that `some_float` is set to something above `1.0`?

Comment: `static_assert` works on compile time only, it cannot check the value of `some_float `, because it doesn't really exist at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_float` must be `constexpr`

```
constexpr float some_float = 3.0;
```

If you define `some_float` simply as `float`, can be used in an `assert()`, that works runtime; not in a `static_assert()`, that is checked compile time.

Moreover: in C++11 it's required a string for an error message

```
static_assert ( some_float > 1.0f , "!" );  
//..................................^^^ error message
```